# MERN applying href to render/return

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am progressing in MERN stack when I ran into an issue displaying some data as an href onto the page.

I can return the data to the screen, so far only in an un-ordered list.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './customers.css';

class Customers extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        customers: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch( '/api/customers')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched..', customers)));
}

render() {
  return (
        <div>
         <h2>Customers</h2>
          <ul>
            {this.state.customers.map(customer => 
                <li key={customer.id}>{ customer.firstName } { customer.lastName } - <a href={ customer.email }>{ customer.email }</a></li>
                                                                                     // ^^ problem is here ^^
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Customers;
```

Everything works until I add the href in the list item above.

The error I get in the console is as follows:

```
 Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/customers from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
```

The page initially loads blank, but when I refresh, the data appears along with the email in an href format.

How do I prevent this error from occurring?

### Edit

Here is the package.json within my client folder:

```
{
 "name": "client",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^16.13.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
   "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: I assume you set up [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for your dev environment or you would not get that sort of error. It looks like the back end is returning a 500 on your first request which is a request to http://localhost:5000/api/customers. If you can't find the error on the server you could try to remove the prosy from package.json and provide full url `http://localhost:5000/api/customers` in client code (install a CORS plugin in your browser).  You can then see if, when and how your client code is sending invalid requests.

Comment: @HMR - I just added the package.json file from within my client folder.

Comment: You should also [check the response ok status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) before setting state. Your code might eventually error out when trying to render `undefined.email` but the root cause is till that your server returns http 500 status on the first request. I can't say if it's because your JS creates a wrong request or if it's because your server code has an error. Try opening `http://localhost:5000/api/customers` before opening your application, if you don't get an error then it's most likely a server code problem.

Comment: @HMR - Thank you, kind sir.